# Deterministic topological order in scala graph

Tags: scala, sorting, graph-algorithm

I'm using [scala-graph](http://scala-graph.org) library to build directional graph and to retrieve its nodes in topological order. Since there can be many possibilities for a topological order of a graph, I need to have deterministic result for topological order for graphs that are equal and built in the same way.

This small app highlights the problem

```
import scalax.collection.Graph
import scalax.collection.GraphEdge.DiEdge
import scalax.collection.GraphPredef._

object MainApp extends App {

  // Creates new graph for every call
  // val is not an option
  def graph: Graph[String, DiEdge] = Graph(
    "A" ~> "B",
    "A" ~> "C",
    "A" ~> "D",
    "B" ~> "E",
    "B" ~> "F",
    "C" ~> "G",
    "C" ~> "H",
    "D" ~> "F",
    "D" ~> "G"
  )

  val results = 1 to 20 map { _ =>
    graph.topologicalSort.mkString("")
  }

  println(results.tail.forall(_ == results.head))
}
```

This app prints false.

Is there a way to build deterministic topological sort of a graph using api of scala-graph library? Writing an algorithm from scratch of doing so would be my last option.

Answer (score 1):

According to the implementation of the function [on github](https://github.com/scala-graph/scala-graph/commit/df2ceff2ff01fdaa51c2160dc506f96dcf011915), the nodes are gathered using a `ComponentTraverser` which is obtained with

```
def componentTraverser(parameters: Parameters = Parameters(), subgraphNodes: (NodeT) ⇒ Boolean = anyNode, subgraphEdges: (EdgeT) ⇒ Boolean = anyEdge, ordering: ElemOrdering = noOrdering): ComponentTraverser
```

Then the `topologicalSort` is called on it. You could force the topological sort to be deterministic by giving an ordering on the value of your nodes to get a `ComponentTraverser` and then call the sort function yourself. *Solution not tested though.*

Comment: I tried this approach before posting the question and it does not work. As mentioned by Peter Empen here https://github.com/scala-graph/scala-graph/issues/41, something similar should work as soon as topological sort is `fully integrated into the library`